# Raspberry-pi - DHT11 + Relay trigger

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am a complete noob when it comes to Python and the Raspberry Pi unit but I am figuring it out.

I am working on a script to monitor the current temperature of my greenhouse that I am building. When the temp gets to 28C, I would like for it to activate my relay which will turn on the fan. At 26C the relay should turn off.

Build info:
Raspberry Pi 3 
dht11 tempurature - GPIO pin 20
single relay board - GPIO pin 21

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11   
import time
import datetime
from time import sleep

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

# Set relay pins as output
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)

# read data using pin 20
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=20)

while True:
result = instance.read()
tempHI = 28
tempLOW = 26
if result >= tempHI 
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH) #turn GPIO pin 21 on
ifels result < tempLOW
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW) #Turn GPIO pin 21 off
time.sleep(1)
```

The current errors I am getting:

```
python ghouse.py
File "ghouse.py", line 19
result = instance.read()
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Python uses indentation to group blocks. Read  https://docs.python.org/release/3.4.3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming and use a python aware editor.  Then add four space below the line `while True:`.

Answer (score 1):

For the current error you're facing, keep in mind that **Python relies *heavily* on indentation**. It's not like other languages such as C++ and Java that use curly braces to arrange statements.

To fix the indentation in your code, please see below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11   
import time
import datetime
from time import sleep

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

# Set relay pins as output
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)

# read data using pin 20
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=20)

while True:
    result = instance.read()
    tempHI = 28
    tempLOW = 26
    if result >= tempHI:
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH) #turn GPIO pin 21 on
    ifels result < tempLOW:
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW) #Turn GPIO pin 21 off
time.sleep(1)
```

In any `if`, `else`, `elif`, `for`, or `while` statement, the code that you want to execute must be indented within the statement in order for it to run, or else you will get the error that you are currently seeing.

There are a few more errors in your code but I'll let you figure out the rest! Welcome to programming in Python and using Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What is really throwing me off is the fact that I script will run through the first line with the if statement in it but gets stuck with the else statement, complaining about a syntax error:

pi@raspberrypi:~/dht11_python/DHT11_Python-master $ python ghouse.py 
  File "ghouse.py", line 26
    else result < tempLOW:
              ^